# bash: wait for specific command output before continuing

Tags: bash, wait, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know there are several posts asking similar things, but none address the problem I'm having.

I'm working on a script that handles connections to different `Bluetooth low energy` devices, reads from some of their handles using `gatttool` and dynamically creates a `.json` file with those values.

The problem I'm having is that `gatttool` commands take a while to execute (and are not always successful in connecting to the devices due to `device is busy` or similar messages). These "errors" translate not only in wrong data to fill the `.json` file but they also allow lines of the script to continue writing to the file (e.g. adding extra `}` or similar). An example of the commands I'm using would be the following:

```
sudo gatttool -l high -b <MAC_ADDRESS> --char-read -a <#handle>
```

How can I approach this in a way that I can wait for a certain output? In this case, the ideal output when you `--char-read` using `gatttool` would be:

```
Characteristic value/description: some_hexadecimal_data`
```

This way I can make sure I am following the script line by line instead of having these "jumps".

Comment: `grep` is the program you need here.

Comment: @nrz how do you propose I use it? I have tried adding `grep Characteristic` to the `gatttool` command but it does not do what I want, which is wait until I get the output I want (here I could use `grep`, but `grep` itself does not wait) and then proceed to run the next line of the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` allows you to filter the output of `gatttool` for the data you are looking for.

If you are actually looking for a way to wait *until* a *specific* output is encountered before continuing, [expect](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/) might be what you are looking for.

From the manpage:

```
expect [[-opts] pat1 body1] ... [-opts] patn [bodyn]
         waits  until  one of the patterns matches the output of a spawned
         process, a specified time period has passed, or an end-of-file is
         seen.  If the final body is empty, it may be omitted.
```

Comment: this looks promising! I'll come back to this after I run some tests :)